# How to hide error messge div onfocus input field in Angular 7?

Tags: angular, angular7

I need to hide the custom validation message div when focus on the input field. Any one have solution for this?

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Password</label>
   <div class="col-sm-6">
     <input type="password" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Password" formControlName="newPassword" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.newPassword.errors }">
   </div>
   <div *ngIf="submitted && f.newPassword.errors" class="invalid-feedback" class="font-cherry font-size-12">
     <div *ngIf="f.newPassword.errors.minlength">Password must be at least 6 characters</div>
   </div>
   <div *ngIf="passwordRequired != ''" class="font-cherry font-size-12">{{passwordRequired}}</div>
</div>
```

i need to hide passwordRequired div when changing the input field.

Comment: please share your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Can Check with `event.target.value` if `minlength` is not 6 it will give u error otherwise it will not give u error

**HTML**

```
<input type="password" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Password" (input)="check($event)">
<div class="error_message" [hidden]="errormessage">Error Message</div>
```

**TS**

```
errormessage:boolean = true;

message:any;
check(e) {
this.message = e.target.value
  if (this.message.length <= 6){
    this.errormessage = false;
  } else {
    this.errormessage = true;
  }
}
```

**CSS**

```
.error_message{
  color: red;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the updateOn is 'blur'.

```
<input [(ngModel)]="name" [ngModelOptions]="{updateOn: 'blur'}">
```

Or

```
new FormControl('', {updateOn: 'blur'});
```

https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#note-on-performance

Comment: I don't need to blur button ineed to hide <div *ngIf="passwordRequired != ''" class="font-cherry font-size-12">{{passwordRequired}}</div> when curser focused on input field

Comment: <input (input)="doSomething()">

Answer (score 0):

You can use the  event in your input

HTML

```
<input type="password" (focus)="passwordFocus()" />
<div *ngIf="isErrorVisible> </div>
```

TS

```
passwordFocus() {
  isErrorVisible = false;
}
```